# What is the best method to manage a user list in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a chat room application using socket.io but I am having issue understanding the correct and simplest method to keep the chat room user list updated.

At the moment when the client joins the chat room it is sent the user list and updates the user list panel using the below code:

```
  socket.on('names', function(channel,nicks){
    for (var nick in nicks) {
        $('#users').append('<li class="list-group-item" id="' + nick + '">' + nick + '</li>');
    }
  });
```

but at the moment it doesn't account for when another user joins or leaves after this point so the user list is the same for the whole duration from the moment that the client joined.

These events are triggered when another user joins or leaves:

```
  socket.on('join', function(channel,nick){
    // need to add the user to the user list, sort the user list
    // alphabetically and then update the list group html
  });

  socket.on('part', function(channel,nick){
    // need to delete the user from the user list, sort the user list
    // alphabetically and then update the list group html
  });

  socket.on('quit', function(nick){
    // need to delete the user from the user list, sort the user list
    // alphabetically and then update the list group html
  });
```

What should I be looking at to accomplish what I need here?

I am guessing that rather than relaying on the server response and building the HTML from that, I should keep a user list array on the client side, updated based on the server responses, and then re-build the HTML from that. Just need point in the right direction really ...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to tackle this is to re-render the list whenever it changes. However, for large lists, this can be inefficient and you could save a lot of time by simply adding an ID to each element, then updating or removing them using it.

This process can become a little complex with jQuery, as you'll be managing your model inside the DOM, rather than inside your code. It's definitely possible though.

An alternative approach is to look at a library like [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

React asks you to describe what your interface looks like. Then it will be responsible for re-rendering it whenever you change the model. As a bonus, it checks against the last state of the DOM and only applies updates to bits that have changed.

```
var UserList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    users: []
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    // set up socket listeners

    // every time you want to update the user list
    this.setState({ users: updatedVersionOfUsers });
  },
  render: function() {
    var users = this.state.users;

    // describe what this component should look like
    return (
      <ul>
        {users.map(function(user) {
          return (
            <li className='list-group-item'>{user}</li>
          );
        }}
      </ul>
    );
  }
})
```

Now, all you have to think about is making sure the model (`this.state.users`) is up to date. So long as you update it with `this.setState`, then React will do the rest.

You can even use React alongside jQuery. Simply find the element that you want this React component to live inside and render it there.

```
React.render(
  <UserList />,
  $('#someElement')[0]
);
```

There's a [great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BF58ZJ1ZQxY) by Ryan Florence on integrating React into an existing project, rather than re-writing it all.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I'd been away so hadn't noticed it until now. I understand (I think) about using React, but I don't understand in your example `// set up socket listeners`, and "Now, all you have to think about is making sure the model (`this.state.users`) is up to date. So long as you update it with `this.setState`, then React will do the rest." Could you give me an example of how I integrate this in to the current code (I put the socket events in the existing question). Just a simple example will do and I will work out the rest. Thank you.